# mysql - query length limitation

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

I have some query which it's text is very large.

```
SELECT id FROM my_table WHERE name IN ('name1','name2',...)
```

- Each name is ~100 chars.
- The table contains 10M rows,
- The field name is indexed.

I've noticed that beyond some threshold, let's say 26K, the performance drops and the query takes ~10 times slower.

For example:

25K names took 0.27 sec

26K names took 3.19 sec

Is there any limitation on the query length (ie the sql text itself)?
Anything else?

Comment: the performance in speed could be a hardware problem? Did you check the memory use? If the memory goes up to 100% , the computer can switch to virtual memory on your harddrive, this will be super slow then

Comment: The result for you IN clause come from an externale query???

Comment: Why not create a table with an indexed column holding all the names in the IN(), and then join that to your first table?

Comment: @scaisEdge no, from out source.

Comment: @Strawberry it's dynamic list which provide by the users

Comment: In which case it would be a temporary table - but it *might* still be quicker (although I have my doubts)

Comment: @Strawberry I'm not sure what you mean, to add temp table for each query?

Comment: Yep. Drop and create.

Comment: @Strawberry what about create table time?

Comment: Yep, that's a factor too.

Answer (score 0):

There are limitation related  to the IN clause  content

```
The number of values in the IN list is limited by the max_allowed_packet value.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet
```

but for improve performance you could try also to use  a subquery instead of IN clause

```
SELECT id 
FROM my_table m
INNER JOIN  (
  select name 
  from my_table_temp
) t ON t.name  = m.name
```

if the values  for name in IN clause are obtained  from external source try eval the possibile of store this result in a temp table  and use this temp table fon the JOIN

or if the external name are few .. you could build a subquery as  union

```
select 'name1' name
union 
select  'name2' 
....
```

and then

```
SELECT id 
FROM my_table m
INNER JOIN  (    
  select 'name1' name
  union 
  select  'name2' 
) t ON t.name  = m.name
```

Comment: This is almost certainly the correct approach but in OP's case he needs to build a temporary table first with the User's values in it, then use that for the constraint.

Comment: But why a subquery?

Comment: @scaisEdge the value of max_allowed_packet value in my db is 104857600 (100MB) while my query start to be slow when the sql string is > 1MB

Comment: the query become slow because the IN clause is as  several OR clause  . .. for this i suggest you of eval a INNER JOIN  ..  this work as  a single JOIN  (and not as several OR select)  with proper index  on name column this should mantain  the performance  ..  without degrade..

Comment: @mclafee - What is the value of `net_buffer_length`?

Comment: @scaisEdge - I'm pretty sure the Optimizer turns `ORs` into `IN` (when appropriate).

Comment: @RickJames  ..  The IN clause is executed  as  a sequence of OR  ...  the difference i between   IN clause  or A JOIN for the IN clause content...the JOIN is executed  as a single intersection between key values

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two ways to run this query:

1. Use the index on name and look up each name in the list using the index.
2. Scan the table and look up each name in the list, not using an index.

MySQL actually optimizes the second method, by sorting the list of names.  You should check the query plans for the two queries, to validate whether or not the index is being used.

MySQL has to decide which way is better.  It does so using statistics and other available information.  What you are observing is that the cutoff between the two methods may not be at exactly the right point, for this example.

If this is the case, you can use the `USE INDEX` hint to ensure that MySQL uses the index, even when the `IN` list is long.